# Django: An explanation of (\d+)

Tags: python, django

In the django book, and on the django website, `\d+` is used to capture data from the url. The syntax is never explain, nor is the importance of D or the () beyond the fact that you can specify the number of characters in that part of the url. How, exactly/in what order, are these variables passed to the function? Hoe, exactly, does the syntax work? How do you implement it? Don't forget to explain the `()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without further information, I'd guess it's a regular expression (or "regex" for short).  These are a common string-processing mechanism used in many programming languages.  In Python they are handled with [the `re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).  If you want to learn more about them you might want to check out a general regex tutorial like http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 6):

That is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). `\d` means digit, and `+` means "one or more". Putting it in parens specifies that it's a capturing group. The contents of each capturing group are passed to the handler function in the order they appear within the regex.

Python's regex library is [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

As another example, a more complex regex might be `(\d+)/(\d+)` which would capture two different sets of one or more digits separated by a slash, and pass them in as two arguments (the first digit string as the first argument, the second digit string as the second argument) to the handler function.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to a digit regular expression used to capture the numeric ID from the URI.

Hi-REST conventions call for URI for GET/POST/...  to be terminated by an ID of the resource, and in this cases it is looking for a numerical ID - `\d+` being one or more numbers)

Enclosing it in parenthesis is simply a convention that assist Django in parsing the regex.

Example:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0486653552](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486653552)